# Is it able to resume downloading when the connection is lost in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.http import FileResponse
def send_file():
    #some processes
    response = FileResponse(open(file_name, 'rb'),as_attachment=True)
    return response
```

The connection sometimes lost. I want to resume downloading the file. How can I do that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a iteration for control the download. Here is a example [Download large file in python with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)